# Defining Piecewise function using an Interval object

Tags: functions, piecewise, intervals

I was trying to define a Piecewise function using a previously defined `Interval` object (that is the union of several intervals). However, I realised that I wasn't getting the right behaviour when trying to either plot or evaluate the function. If I define the function using the lower and upper limits of the interval everything works correctly though.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
f = Piecewise[{{1, Element[x, Interval[{0, 1}]]}}, 0]
g = Piecewise[{{1, 0 < x < 1}}, 0]
```

When running

```
Plot[{f, g}, {x, 0, 2}]
```

only g is plotted and not f. The same happens if I try to evaluate the functions at a specific x value.

Why is that the case? Is it possible to use `Piecewise` together with an `Interval` object or should I always use the upper and lower limits?

Answer (score 1):

- `RegionMember` work for `Interval`.

```
f = Piecewise[{{1, RegionMember[Interval[{0, 1}]]@{x}}}, 0];
g = Piecewise[{{1, 0 < x < 1}}, 0];
Plot[{f, g}, {x, 0, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Opacity[.2], AbsoluteThickness[10]], 
   Blue}]
```

[image]

- When we want to use `Element`, we need to write such as `Element[{1/2}, Interval[{0, 1}]]`  `(*True *)`.

```
h = Piecewise[{{1, Element[{x}, Interval[{0, 1}]]}}, 0];
Plot[h, {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I still don't understand why `Element` doesn't work though. From the documentation on `RegionMember`: "`Element` can be used to test region membership for constant regions". Why is the [0,1] interval defined in my code example not considered to be a constant region?

Answer (score 0):

```
f = Piecewise[{{1, Between[x, Interval[{0, 1}]]}}, 0]
g = Piecewise[{{1, 0 < x < 1}}, 0]

Plot[{f, g}, {x, 0, 2}
 , PlotStyle -> {
   {AbsoluteThickness[5], Lighter@Yellow}
   , {Dashed, Blue}
   }
 ]
```

[image]